# simplest php dropdown box

Tags: php, forms, select

I have a simple dropdow box, I want to get the value of the selected item with php. If anyone can help me with it please.

```
<form id="s" method="post">
<select name="size">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php
---
echo "selected size".$selected;
?>
```

Comment: You are trying to get a client side value with a server side language... Unless you post/submit back to the server PHP can not read the selected value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you put everything in one file:

```
  <form id="s" method="post">
   <select name="size">
   <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
  </select> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['size'])) {
  echo "selected size: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['size']);
}
?>
```

Comment: However this WILL reload the page.  The only way to do it without reloading the page is to use javascript.

Comment: @John - Remember, you'll need to submit the form for this all to happen, per @scunliffe's comment.

Comment: Of course it will reload the page. OP said nothing about not reloading the page.

Comment: This, of course adds an XSS hole to your code... never ever even in the simplest example echo back raw POST data. `htmlspecialchars($_POST['size'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="rider_select"> 
 <option value="">Select Rider</option>

    <?php
     foreach ($riderlist as $rows) {
     $rname = $rows['name'];
     $rnum = $rows['number'];
     $rider_full = $rname.'-'.$rnum;
     ?>

 <option value="<?php echo $rname.'-'.$rnum; ?>"
 <?= (($rider_fromdb == $rider_full) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>
<?php echo $rname.'-'.$rnum; ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Please explain why/how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: If you are looking for simplest php foreach dropdown then my answer will be helpful for you